# Can't write anything in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I try to write a DataFrame into any kind of file format. I tried to reinstall spark several times in different ways and different versions, but receieve the same error everytime, even on another machine. Currently using Spark 3.3.1 on Hadoop 2.7 locally on Windows 11:

```
data = [[1, 43, 41], [2, 43, 41], [3, 43, 4]]
x = spark.createDataFrame(data)
x.write.csv('qqq')
```

And receive this:

```
  File "D:\venvs\spark2\spark_hw.py", line 77, in <module>
    x.write.csv('qqq')
  File "D:\venvs\spark2\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 1240, in csv
    self._jwrite.csv(path)
  File "D:\venvs\spark2\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "D:\venvs\spark2\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "D:\venvs\spark2\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o44.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x.write.format("csv").save("path/where/file/should/go")
```

will write your dataframe to a csv to the path specified in the save method

Comment: i have tried it too, and received this 
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o81.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.